# Can't access all values of array

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js, mariadb

I am getting a row from mysql into an array using node-mariasql.
When I print this array out using my Winston logger, I get this:

```
steamid=76561198053558238, tradePartnerId=93292510, tradeToken=T3dZTnlq, autoSendWinnings=1, profilePrivacy=0, earnings=0.00, lastKnownName=jdK jdK, avatar=https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/49/4955f3be7e9b9d16e8fc0b16ed2407ba9b4c563c.jpg, avatarLarge=https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/49/4955f3be7e9b9d16e8fc0b16ed2407ba9b4c563c_full.jpg
```

If I print out the value for "steamid", I get this as a return:
    76561198053558238
However, if I print out the value for "autoSendWinnnings" or "profilePrivacy", I get "undefined" as a return.
Why is that? What am I doing wrong? I don't think it is a MySQL related issue, because if I print out the whole array, I obviously get all values.

Still, I'll append the relevant code here.

```
statements['get_user'] = sql.prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE steamid=:steamid');
function getUser(steamid, callback) {
    sql.query(statements.get_user({ steamid: steamid }), { useArray: true }, function(err, rows) {
        if(err)
            logger.error('A MySQL error occured: ' + err);

        callback(rows);
    });
}

getUser('76561198053558238' function(user) {
    logger.debug(user); // I get the whole array here
    logger.debug(user.steamid); // I get the value for steamid here
    logger.debug(user.autoSendWinnings); // I get undefined here
});
```

Thanks in advance,
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I'd bet your `steamid` string gets converted to a number at some point and since 76561198053558238 cannot be represented exactly by a double, you get 76561198053558240. Though it'd be weird that the `logger.debug(user.steamid);` would still display the correct id, if that is the case.

Comment: Also, show us your definition for the table.

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb here and guess that autoSendWinnings has a spelling mistake, and profilePrivacy actually is undefined but the logger can figure that out and print it as 0 by using the object definition.

Comment: @Ilja that has got nothing to do with my actual problem, lol. There's no issue with the value of "steamid". Just that I can't get the values for some other keys...
this is the table structure: http://prntscr.com/agdnvo

Comment: @chugadie Nope, I cannot identify any spelling mistake.
Also, If I set profilePrivacy to 1, it displays it correctly in the array, so it's not actually undefined.

Comment: @LuucDev What Node SQL library are you using?

Comment: Also, will `sql.query` automatically return the row itself, if only a single row is found? `callback(rows);` seems like it'd pass a set of rows, which then would naturally not have a `.autoSendWinnings` attribute.

Comment: @Ilja if it wouldn't I shouldn't be able to get the steamid either, should I?

Comment: @LuucDev that we can't now, if we don't know the library in use and what it does. It could construct some "ResultSet" or what have you object to store results. It might then for example store used predicates in that. But that's not likely, I admit, and also `console.log(user)` would (likely) display `[object ...]` or something.

Comment: Actually: `logger.debug(user); //` **I get the whole array here** is all we need to know. an Array will not have a property autoSendWinnings. Members of said array will.

Comment: Btw providing the debug outputs would've been super.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback receives an `Array` of result rows. For reasons unknown said `Array` has a property `steamid`.

Try

```
getUser('76561198053558238', function(users) {
    logger.debug(users);
    logger.debug(users[0].steamid);
    logger.debug(users[0].autoSendWinnings);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, nevermind, that was the problem.
I thought, as long as there is only one row returned, I don't need to specify the row... Thanks :)